# Excel VBA inserting row

Tags: vba, excel

I have a little problem with my macro.
I just want to insert a dynamic number of rows, above a specific row which should copy everything from that specific row. So formatting, formulas, text, merged cells basically everything.

Now my code actually inserts the number of rows I need and it does copy the formatting. The stuff I am missing is the text/formulas in the cells and the cells are not merged at all(like in the row below).

what I have so far is this:

```
Set ins = wsCopyTo.Range("A100")

Do While k > 0 = True


   ins.EntireRow.Insert

k = k - 1

Loop
```

now for easy reasons lets just assume k is 100 since as I said the number of rows which I insert is actually correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
Sub copyXrows()
Dim ins As Range
Dim k As Integer
Set ins = Tabelle1.Range("A10")

ins.Select
k = 2
Do While k > 0 = True

ins.EntireRow.Copy
ins.EntireRow.Insert

k = k - 1

Loop

End Sub
```

You miss a entirerow.copy command.